# TCP Ports for managing clusters

Tags: azure-service-fabric

What outgoing TCP ports are needed to fully manage a Service Fabric cluster in Azure? I was aware of 19080 being needed to access the Service Fabric Explorer but then today I discovered that 19000 is needed to publish to a cluster. This makes me wonder if there are other ports.

I need to make an official request to my IT department to open up outgoing TCP Ports and I want to be sure I cover everything in one request. Are there other ports I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default port for connecting to cluster from visual studio or powershell is 19000, but can be changed when you create the cluster, using either the Azure portal or ARM template deployments.

Port 19080 is used by the Service Fabric Explorer.

There are no other ports used by Service Fabric itself, but your applications can be configured to use other ports, but this is something you control.

Comment: One clarification: port 19080 is used by the cluster's HTTP gateway, which serves the management REST API in addition to the SFX web UI.

Comment: I'm finding that there needs to be at least one other port besides 19000 and 19080. If you only open those ports, attempts to publish/copy an application to the store will fail. I'm currently trying to nail down what other ports are required.

Comment: I am not able to telnet port 19000 from another vm. I am trying to add a new node to service fabric. I am getting the below error.
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...